# how to display listview more faster in android

Tags: android, listview, load

i want to load mobile contacts and sim contacts into my `listview` with indicators. The indicators depends on server side list. The `listview` contains 2 `imageviews` and 2 `textviews` so that it takes more time to load please provide any solution for this issue.

Comment: You can use lazy loading for image and  recycle the list view which faster your listview scrolling.If needed, i can set any example as well

Comment: plz post the example

Answer (score 0):

First, every call to the server in order to retrieve new data must be perform with an [AsynckTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or similar implementation.

Second, use the [holder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder), While this sounds more complex than the stander way, “it is approximately 15 % faster then using the findViewById() method”.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder) a really nice tutorial (8.4. Holder Pattern)